# Python logging library - beyond logging levels

Tags: python, logging

The python logging library allows to log based on different levels:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-levels
But I would like to use it to log based on custom tags,  for example "show_intermediate_results" or "display_waypoints_in_the_code" or "report_time_for_each_module" and so on...
Those tags cannot be measured in a severity ladder, during development i would sometimes want to see them and sometimes not depending on what i am developing/debugging at the moment.
So the question is if I can use the logging library to do that?
Btw, i DO want to use the library and not write something by myself because i want it to be thread safe.

Comment: You can use different loggers https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging

Comment: I'm not sure that will help me because I am more interested in controlling the *console* printing. A different logger may help to direct output to different log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects), you can use `logging.Filter` objects with `Logger` and `Handler` instances

> for more sophisticated filtering than is provided by levels.